# Is there an easier way to display text using C++ and OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Using C++ and OpenGL (with GLUT) I am trying to display some dynamic text on the users screen. The text I am trying to display is the time it took to calculate everything needed to render Mandelbrot set.

So far I have managed to do it this way:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "Time: " << end_time-start_time;
const std::string& tmp = stream.str();
const char* cstr = tmp.c_str();
strcpy(message, cstr );
int len = (int) strlen(message);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(20.0, 80.0, 0.0);
glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, message[i]);
}
glPopMatrix();
```

As I am not very familliar with C++ and OpenGL I couldn't figure out a more concise way to do it but this seems to me to be way too complicated to display just a single sentance.

Can you recommend a better or less complicated way to do this? Any advice or cricism is welcome.

Comment: maybe just use console to output or show it on window title?

Comment: you can expect anything 2D to be quite complex since opengl is designed for 3D

Comment: That looks fairly simple compared to what glut is doing under the hood for you. Personally I'd pick some higher level interfaces than even glut if you've got any real ui work to do though.

Comment: @SvenNilsson 2D in OpenGL is no more complex than 3D in OpenGL; it's just a matter of setting the Z coordinate to zero...

Comment: How is this too complicated? If it's too long you could encapsulate it in its own function. Also as @Flexo said, glut is doing most of the work for you. OpenGL doesn't know what is text and what isn't - there are just primitives going through a pipeline. Glut happens to tell OpenGL to render rectangles with a font texture on them - that's how you get text.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two shall I perhaps say non-intuitive instead of complex. What I meant was that any 2D you draw is actually 3D that appears to be 2D due to perfect camera settings and billboard quads being drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably more succinct (c++11):

```
void showTime()
{
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(20.0, 80.0, 0.0);
  glScalef(0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
  glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
  for (auto ch : std::to_string(end_time - start_time))
  {
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, ch);
  }
  glPopMatrix();
}
```